# Pointer vs Reference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I know this is already a commonly asked question, but I'm more curious about how pointers and references behave at a lower level (like how compiler deals with them, and how they look like in memory), and I didn't find a solution, so here I am.

At first I was wondering if an array can be passed as a parameter without being cast (or decay) into a pointer. More specifically. I would like the following code:

```
void func(?? arr) {
    cout << sizeof(arr) << "\n";
}

int main() {
    int arr[4];
    func(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

to output `16` instead of `8`, which is the size of a pointer.

First I tried

```
void func(int arr[4]);
```

Hoping that specifying the size can keep the property of an array, but `arr` is still treated as a pointer.

Then I found something that worked:

```
void func(int (&arr)[4]);
```

But it confused me.

In the past I was under the impression that although pointers and references had different meanings, they had the same behavior when the code was actually executed.

I got that idea from my own experiments:

```
void swap(int* a, int* b) {
    int c = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = c;
}
int main() {
    int a = 3, b = 5;
    swap(&a, &b);
}
```

and

```
void swap(int& a, int& b) {
    int c = a;
    a = b;
    b = c;
}
int main() {
    int a = 3, b = 5;
    swap(a, b);
}
```

were compiled into the same assembly code, and so did

```
int main() {
    int a = 3;
    int& b = a;
    b = 127;
    return 0;
}
```

and

```
int main() {
    int a = 3;
    int* b = &a;
    *b = 127;
    return 0;
}
```

I turned off optimization and both g++ and clang++ showed this result.

Also my thought on the first experiment:

when thinking in terms of memory, `swap` should have its own stack frame and local variables. Having `a` in `swap` directly mapped to the `a` in `main` didn't make much sense to me. It was as if the `a` in `main` magically appeared in the stack frame of `swap`, where it shouldn't belong. So it didn't surprise me that it got compiled into the same assembly as the pointer version. Maybe the magic of reference was achieved by a pointer underneath the hood. But now I'm not sure.

So how does a compiler handle references and how do references look like in memory? Are they variable that occupies space? And how can I explain the result of my experiments and the array problem?

Comment: Your question is actually a combination of several different questions, each of which is a duplicate. VTC.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  They should dig into this with great detail

Comment: How pointers and references work under the hood is an implementation detail. Usually, they both work by storing a memory address. The reason your array reference code gives a different size is not related to these details. That behavior is mandated by the standard and will work that way regardless of the implementation. The actual values you see may vary, but the example with an array parameter will always return the size of a pointer and the example with the reference to an array will always return the size of the actual array.

Comment: A function argument like `int arr[4]` is a big lie the language is telling you. It is a behavior inherited from C, kept around for backwards compatibility. Array type arguments are always just pointers in disguise. It is identical to `int * arr`, which is why you get the size of an pointer instead of the size of an array. This causes a lot of confusion, specially leading new users to think arrays are just pointers.

Comment: Side note: C++ doesn't require stacks. They are merely another, albeit the most common by far,  implementation detail.

Comment: just because something compiles to the same assembly in one situation does not mean that it is the same in general. References can be implemented via pointers, but that does not make them pointers

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/Kr1s8G414 for one possible example of how the code compiles differently. Set `-O0` to `-O2` if you want to see it optimized. In this case, both of your versions differ only in the value of a compile-time constant expression.

Comment: Note that the pointer version of `void func(int (&arr)[4]);` is actually `void func(int (*arr)[4]);` in which case you could get the correct size with `sizeof *arr` too. So yes, this is possible with pointers too. That's also why you have to specify a size. `void func(int (&arr)[]);` won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old C idiom is, that arrays get turned into pointers to the array type, when a function is called. And that is mostly still true für C++.

So for the details of it, let's look at two functions taking an integer argument, first:

```
void f(int x) { x = 42; }              // function called with x by value
void g(int& x) { x = 42; }             // function called with x by reference
```

As `f()` is called by value, a copy of the argument is made, and the assignment `x = 42;` inside the function has effectively no effect for the caller of the function. But for `g()`, the assignment of `x` becomes visible to the caller:

```
int a = 0, b = 0;                        // initialize both a and b to zero
f(a);                                    // a is not changed, because f is called by value
g(b);                                    // b is changed, because g is called by reference
std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl; // prints 0 42
```

For arrays, the same rules should hold, but don't. So let's try it:

```
void farr(int x[4]) { x[0] = 42; }       // hypothetical call by value
void garr(int (&x)[4]) { x[0] = 42; }    // call by reference
```

And let's call these functions:

```
int c[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, d[4] = { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
farr(c);                        // call by value?
garr(d);                        // call by reference
for(unsigned i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    std::cout << c[i] << (i < 3 ? ", " : "\n");
for(unsigned i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    std::cout << d[i] << (i < 3 ? ", " : "\n");
```

The unexpected result is, that the `farr()` function (unlike the `f` function before) does modify its array, too. The reason is an old C idiom: Because arrays must not be copied directly by assignment, functions cannot be called with arrays by value. Therefore array declarations in parameter lists are automatically converted into a pointer to the first element of the array. So the following four function declarations are syntactically identical in C:

```
void farr1(int a[]) {}
void farr2(int a[4]) {}
void farr3(int a[40]) {}
void farr4(int *a) {}
```

Being compatible with C, C++ took over that property. So it is not a syntactical error (but likely causes undefined behaviour!) to call `farr2()` or `farr3()` with an array of different size. Furthermore, though, references come in in C++. And yes, as you already suspected, a reference to an array is internally represented as a pointer to the first array element. But, and that is the advantage of C++: If you call a function, that expects a reference to an array (and not just an array or a pointer), the size of array is actually validated!

So, calling `farr()` with an int-Array of size 5 is possible, calling `garr()` with the same leads to an compiler error. That gives you better type checking, so you should use it, whereever possible. And it even allows you to pass the array size to a function by using a template:

```
template<std::size_t N>
void harr(int (&x)[N]) { for(std::size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) x[i] = i*i; }
```

Comment: "to call g() or h() with an array of different size" I think you mean `farr` and `harr`. And I don't think it is possible to cause UB by passing arrays of different size, though the more I learn about arrays the less I know about arrays.

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing out that error - I mean farr2() and farr3(). I will correct that. And it is easy to cause segfaults and other undefined behaviour, if passing a different array size: If a function expects an array of size 10 and modifies all elements of that array, but gets only passed in an array of size 5, then you will corrupt the stack or heap.

Comment: ah ok, now I get what you mean. I thought you mean merely passing the parameter could cause ub.